# Watch multiple directories using Forever Monitor

Tags: javascript, node.js, forever, forever-monitor

I'm using Forever Monitor to restart my server whenever I change a server file. However, I also want it to restart when files in another directory changes.

I have a "server" directory, a "client" directory, and a "shared" directory. At the moment, I'm using Forever Monitor to watch the "server" directory. However, I want it to watch the "shared" directory as well. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Why not use [grunt-forever](https://github.com/bustardcelly/grunt-forever)?

Comment: Firstly, I'm not using grunt. I tried using `forever` directly before, but it was missing something, I forgot what. I think it didn't handle errors properly.

Comment: Why not use it then?

Comment: Because there's no reason to, grunt-forever doesn't even solve my problem.

Comment: I think with forever you would need to watch the parent directory and ignore/filter everything else via `watchIgnorePatterns`. [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) does support watching multiple directories and files `nodemon -w . -w ../shared server.js` and is also requireable.

Comment: `grunt watch` would, acompanied with `grunt forever` :)

Comment: Leo isn't using `Grunt` - these comments made me LOL